# .htaccess rewrite where url basename is same as a directory name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory in my file structure named "finder" and I want to rewrite a url that has finder as the basename.  For example take `www.mysite.com/finder`.

Here is the rewrite rule I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^finder/?$ /finder/directory/listings.php [NC,L]
```

Instead of succeeding with a rewrite i'm getting a 404 Page Not Found message.  For what it's worth I have a rewrite rule that is taking this url `www.mysite.com/finder/california` with this rule...

```
RewriteRule ^finder/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]*)/?$ /finder/directory/listings.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

.. and it's working.

I have tried `DirectorySlash Off` to my .htaccess but that's not working either.  Any clues about what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential troublesome areas:

1. The htaccess file with this rule cannot be in the `finder` folder. Make sure it is in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory.
2. There could be an issue with the forward slash in the rewrite.

Tested on Apache 2.2 and 2.4:

- `RewriteRule ^finder/?$ directory/listings.php [NC,L]`
- URL in browser: `http://www.example.com/finder`
- Redirected to: `http://www.example.com/directory/listings.php`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ah yes, I moved the rewrite to DOCUMENT_ROOT as you suggested and it worked. Thanks for the help.